# Django module - absent views model

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm following the goat testing book. And I got the following issue.

I'm running the django server with `python manage.py runserver`.

Yet i'm having this error.

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/andykw/cloned_projects/unit-tests/superlists/superlists/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from lists import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lists'
```

I know there is `views.py` in the app `list`

This is what I have in `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from lists import views

urlpatterns = ['lists.views',
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home_page,name='home'),
]
```

Any ideas are more than welcome.

### update

This is the tree structure my project

```
├── func_tests.py
├── geckodriver.log
├── lists
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── superlists
    ├── manage.py
    └── superlists
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
        │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
        │   └── urls.cpython-36.pyc
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `from superlists import view` (so `super...`)?

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem, the book specifically mentions `lists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the path with the root app name included:

```py
from superlists.lists import views
```

---

### EDIT:

As you've posted your project structure, it seems like your `lists` Django app is **outside** your project's root directory (`./superlists`) - they are on the same level of nesting.

[As the Django documentation specifies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app), when you create a new app using `manage.py startapp [app-name]` it creates a folder with the structure of your `lists` app, but **inside** your first `superlists` folder. It means that by design you should have something like this:

```
└── superlists
    ├── manage.py
    ├── lists
    │   ├── ...
    └── superlists
```

And then the initial answer that I gave you should start working.

Comment: hi @wencakisa, alas no. `    from superlists.lists import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'superlists.lists`

Comment: @AndyK Can you please add your project structure in the question?

Comment: there you go @wencakisa

Comment: @AndyK I've updated my answer with proper solution too. :)

Answer (score 1):

`lists` folder (app) is outside of the project folder currently. Move it inside `superlists` folder.

```
└── superlists
    ├── manage.py
    ├── lists
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    └── superlists
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
        │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
        │   └── urls.cpython-36.pyc
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

`func_tests.py` also has a strange location.